# LetterDict, a dictionary whose keys must be lowercase letters [a-z]

Tags: python, hash-map, bitwise, trie

Looking for any suggestions - alternative design, improvements to readability, improvements to the comments, etc.

---

I implemented this letter dictionary to see if it would faster than a regular dictionary in a Trie implementation. Keys into this dictionary must be lowercase letters. `LetterDict` maintains an integer bitset, `K`, and a list, `V` s.t. if the `o`th lowercase letter is a key in the dictionary, then the `o`th bit of `K` is set and `V` holds the value corresponding to the letter key. For example, the regular dictionary `{'c': 22, 'a': 0, 'b': 11, 'd': 33, 'x': 23, 'j': 10}` would be maintained as:

```
      zy xwvu tsrq ponm lkji hgfe dcba <- letter
      54 3210 9876 5432 1098 7654 3210 <- letter/bit index
K = 0b00_1000_0000_0000_0010_0000_1111 <- keys

     a   b   c   d   j   x  <- keys
V = [0, 11, 22, 33, 10, 23] <- values
```

```
class LetterDictCompact:
    '''A dicitionary whose keys must be lowercase letters [a-z].'''
    
    ORD_a = ord('a')
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.K = 0b0 # keys are lowercase letters [a-z]
        self.V = [] # values can be anything
    
    
    def __contains__(self, key: str) -> bool:
        o = ord(key) - self.ORD_a
        return self.K & (1 << o)
    
    
    def __getitem__(self, key: str):
        present, i = self.__i(key)
        if present:
            return self.V[i]
        raise KeyError(key)
    
    
    def __setitem__(self, key: str, val):
        present, i = self.__i(key)
        if present:
            self.V[i] = val
        else:
            self.V.insert(i, val)
    
    
    def setdefault(self, key: str, defval=None):
        present, i = self.__i(key)
        if present:
            return self.V[i]
        self.V.insert(i, defval)
        return defval
    
    
    # SIDE EFFECT: Modifies self.K
    # As such, __contains__ should not call this method
    def __i(self, key: str) -> tuple[bool, int]:
        o = ord(key) - self.ORD_a
        target = 1 << o
        present = self.K & target
        self.K |= target
        K = self.K
        i = 0
        while (K := K & (K - 1)) & target:
            i += 1
        return present, i
```

I also implemented a version of `LetterDict` that is not as compact because it maintains `V` as a constant-26-length `list` (actually, as a constant-27-length because an extra character is needed to denote the end of a word in the Trie implementation). As mentioned, this version is not as compact, but it does simplify the logic a lot:

```
class LetterDictSparse:
    '''A dicitionary whose keys must be lowercase letters [a-z].'''
    
    NUM_LETTERS = 26 + 1 # + 1 to accomoated Trie.END = chr(ord('z') + 1)
    EMPTY_VALUE = object() # Cannot be `None` because `None` is a possible value
    ORD_a = ord('a')
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.K = 0b0 # keys are lowercase letters [a-z]
        self.V = [self.EMPTY_VALUE] * self.NUM_LETTERS  # values can be anything
    
    
    def __contains__(self, key: str) -> bool:
        o = ord(key) - self.ORD_a
        return self.V[o] != self.EMPTY_VALUE
    
    
    def __getitem__(self, key: str):
        o = ord(key) - self.ORD_a
        if (val := self.V[o]) == self.EMPTY_VALUE:
            raise KeyError(key)
        return val
    
    
    def __setitem__(self, key: str, val):
        o = ord(key) - self.ORD_a
        self.V[o] = val
    
    
    def setdefault(self, key: str, defval=None):
        o = ord(key) - self.ORD_a
        if (val := self.V[o]) == self.EMPTY_VALUE:
            self.V[o] = defval
            return defval
        return val
```

Both of the above implementations of `LetterDict` are correct in as much as I used them to implement a Trie and that Trie passed all the [leetcode Trie tests](https://leetcode.com/problems/implement-trie-prefix-tree/). [Here](https://pastebin.com/uWj46fpi) you can see the code in context.

---

In general, any dictionary whose keys are restricted to fall within a contiguous range of values can be implemented like `LetterDictCompact` and `LetterDictSparese` for some definition of "contiguous range of values" (what's required is that there's a one-to-one mapping between the "contiguous range of values" to the range `[0..N]` for `N` equal to the number of values in the "contiguous range of values").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Counting bits

```py
        K = self.K
        i = 0
        while (K := K & (K - 1)) & target:
            i += 1
```

This loop is counting the number of `1`-bits below the `target` bit.

The [`int.bit_count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=bit_count#int.bit_count) function can give you the population of 1's in any integer, so this loop could be replaced with one statement:

```py
        i = (self.K & (target - 1)).bit_count()
```

Note: In Python 3.9 and earlier, you could use:

```py
        i = bin(self.K & (target - 1)).count("1")
```

but the efficiency of this is questionable due to conversion to string.

## Public -vs- Private

The members `K` and `V` should be named `_k` and `_v` (or even `_keys` and `_vals`)

- The leading underscore, by convention, indicates they are not part of the public interface.
- [PEP 8: The Style Guide for Python Code](https://pep8.org/) recommends all members use `lowercase_lettering`.  Upper case letters are reserved for use in `CONSTANT_VALUES` and `ClassNames`.

## Unused members

The member `K` is unused in `LetterDictSparse`, and should be removed.

Comment: Thanks! Made the changes in github. Just for my future reference:`int.bit_count()` was added in Python 3.10.

Comment: Whoops!  Didn't notice that.  Knew Java has `Integer.bitCount()` for ever (well, since 1.5 anyway), and knew Python integers had `.member_function()` methods.  Opened an IDLE shell, typed `x = 1` and `x.`, pressed tab, saw `bit_count` in the possible completions, searched `bit_count` in the Python docs I had open in my browser, copy-pasted the link, and moved on.  Didn't notice it was a newly added function. :-p   For Python 3.9 and earlier, `i = bin(self.K & (target - 1)).count("1")`

Comment: Still, it's very useful to know about the new function. Thanks again!